# How to change the name of the factors of the variable based on keywords in R?

Tags: r

I have a variable in which there are several levels containing "games" as key word.I can not manually change the levels of the variables .Instead I want to change all levels containing games to a common level.

```
For example

Category
Games x
Games Y
Games Z
Entertainment

What I need is 

Category
Games
Games
Games
Entertainment

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is with package [`forcats`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html), a CRAN package to work with factors.
I will work with `df2`, a copy of the original data.frame.

```
library(forcats)

df2 <- df

new_games <- as.character(df$Category[grep("Games", df$Category)])
df2$Category <- fct_collapse(df$Category, Games = new_games)

df2
#       Category
#1         Games
#2         Games
#3         Games
#4 Entertainment
```

**Data.**

```
df <-
structure(list(Category = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L),
.Label = c("Entertainment", "Games x", "Games Y", 
"Games Z"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by other characters, replace it with blank (`""`) in the 'Category' column

```
df1$Category <- sub("\\s+.*", "", df1$Category)
df1$Category
#[1] "Games"         "Games"         "Games"         "Entertainment"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Category = c("Games x", "Games Y", "Games Z", 
 "Entertainment")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
  ))
```

Comment: @PraveenChougale  You said earlier that it is working.  Can you be specific

Comment: after running that line ,it gives NULL levels

Comment: @PraveenChougale  Can you show the `dput` of the example just like I updated

Comment: The data which I have shown in the example is sample data,In real I have 53 levels .I cant put all those manually in the code

Comment: @PraveenChougale  Can you show the `levels(df1$Category)`

Comment: I got it ..It works  :          mydata$App.Category[grepl("Game",mydata$App.Category)] <- "Games"